# Tolerate deserialization error of one property in ASP.NET Core 6 using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, json.net

I'm currently migrating an ASP.NET MVC app to ASP.NET Core and I'm encountering a deserialization issue. I added NewtonsoftJson as the serializer to my project, just like the old project, but it is a lot less tolerant it seems as the incorrect deserialization of one property in the entire model binding causes the entire web api call go haywire. One incorrect property deserialization makes the model binding process fail. This is not necessarily bad but I need to tolerate errors such as 'Could not convert string to integer'.

This is what I call in the startup class:

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

The configuration:

```
public class SerializationOptionConfigurator : IConfigureNamedOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>
{
  private IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

  public SerializationOptionConfigurator(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
  {
    _accessor = accessor;
  }

  public virtual void Configure(MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions options)
  {
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    options.UseMemberCasing();
    options.SerializerSettings.Error += (sender, args) =>
    {
      Program.Logger.Error(args.ErrorContext.Error, "Something went wrong in the serialization process...");
      args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    };

    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeJsonConverter(_accessor));
  }

  public void Configure(string name, MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions options) => Configure(options);
}
```

The API controller is also pretty vanilla:

```
[Route(Routes.Appointments)]
[ApiController]
public class AppointmentsApiController
{
} 

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Appointment>> Create([FromBody] IEnumerable<Appointment> appointments)
=> await Service.CreateOrUpdateAsync(appointments).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

`args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;` doesn't seem to have any effect on incomplete deserialization. When I set `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter`, the call goes through but the  body is null in the action method.

Naturally, I could look into resolving the issue (and I will), but our app is so big that's is impossible to cover all scenarios, so I need to find a way to configure the model binding process to continue, even when not all properties could be mapped. In my case, the client app sends a string value to an integer property. In the ASP.NET MVC project, this used to work, but not in the ASP.NET Core project.

Could this be related to [this](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2316) bug report of Newtonsoft.Json, or is there a secret config that could solve this issue?

Comment: Could indeed be related, as I was about to suggest using the Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.OnError. Wasn't aware this was an open bug report.

Comment: In [Regression from Json.NET v6: cannot skip an invalid object value type in an array via exception handling #1580](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1580), JamesNK [stated](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1580#issuecomment-358546723) *The error handling feature in Json.NET is very flaky. You might be better off manually parsing the JSON to handle bad content.*.  Probably not what you wanted to hear.

Comment: But can you share a [mcve] (with JSON and data model) giving an example where `args.ErrorContext.Handled = true` fails to work?  Maybe there's specific going on here which could be worked around.

Comment: Also, when you upgraded to ASP.NET Core, did you also upgrade your Json.NET version?  What were your old and new versions?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonSoft 6.0.5, which references Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1, which is the same version in the MVC project. So we could be on to something with issue 1580 here.

Comment: It's somewhat surprising that Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1's error handling works acceptably in MVC but not ASP.NET Core.  Sorry I can't be of more help but I can't really guess why that might be.